# Automatically draw and labels angles of a triangle in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using LaTeX with TikZ to create a (right-angle) triangle. Now I would like to label each angle by adding a half circle and a text label.

Unfortunately I only managed to create a label for the gamma angle. What do I need to do in order to put such a label into the remaining corners?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw(0,0) -- (90:2cm) node[midway,left]{$opposite leg$} -- (0:4cm) node[midway,above right]{$hypotenuse$} -- (0,0) node[midway,below]{$adjacent leg$};
\draw[fill=lightgray, thick] (0,0) -- (0:0.8cm) arc (0:90:0.8cm) node at (45:0.5cm) {$\gamma$} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) No need to add thanks, simply upvote good replies to your questions

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'd use [`tkz-euclide`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide) for this task. It provides a nice macro `\tkzMarkAngle` which is really of help in this case.

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt,png]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (4,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,2);
\draw (O)--(A)--(B)--cycle;

\tkzLabelSegment[below=2pt](O,A){\textit{adjacent leg}}
\tkzLabelSegment[left=2pt](O,B){\textit{opposite leg}}
\tkzLabelSegment[above right=2pt](A,B){\textit{hypotenuse}}

\tkzMarkAngle[fill= orange,size=0.65cm,%
opacity=.4](A,O,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.35](A,O,B){$\gamma$}

\tkzMarkAngle[fill= orange,size=0.8cm,%
opacity=.4](B,A,O)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.6](B,A,O){$\alpha$}

\tkzMarkAngle[fill= orange,size=0.7cm,%
opacity=.4](O,B,A)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.5](O,B,A){$\beta$}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

#### Disclaimer

Hoping that the labels are right.

As [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbjorn-t) was suggesting in [its comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96459/automatically-draw-and-labels-angles-of-a-triangle-in-tikz/96462#comment292781_96462), it is even possible to create square angles thanks to the macro `\tkzMarkRightAngle`. The previous example becomes:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt,png]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (4,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,2);
\draw (O)--(A)--(B)--cycle;

\tkzLabelSegment[below=2pt](O,A){\textit{adjacent leg}}
\tkzLabelSegment[left=2pt](O,B){\textit{opposite leg}}
\tkzLabelSegment[above right=2pt](A,B){\textit{hypotenuse}}

\tkzMarkRightAngle[fill=orange,size=0.5,opacity=.4](A,O,B)% square angle here
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.35](A,O,B){$\gamma$}

\tkzMarkAngle[fill= orange,size=0.8cm,%
opacity=.4](B,A,O)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.6](B,A,O){$\alpha$}

\tkzMarkAngle[fill= orange,size=0.7cm,%
opacity=.4](O,B,A)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.5](O,B,A){$\beta$}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: That's an awesome solution. (And yes, the labels are right. ;-))

Comment: @T.Verron: that's the first thing done after having drawn the triangle :)

Comment: I know the OP specified an arc also for the right angle `\gamma`, but I'll just mention that if one wants a square instead, then one can use `\tkzMarkRightAngle[fill=orange,size=0.5,opacity=.4](A,O,B)`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: it might be a nice addition, thanks. I'll edit as soon as possible.

Answer (score 11):

A solution with 'pure' `tikz` could be:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw(0,0) -- (90:2cm) node[midway,left]{$opposite\ leg$} -- (0:4cm) node[midway,above right]{$hypotenuse$} -- (0,0) node[midway,below]{$adjacent\ leg$};
\draw[fill=lightgray, thick] (0,0) -- (0:0.8cm) arc (0:90:0.8cm) node at (45:0.5cm) {$\gamma$} -- cycle;
\draw[fill=lightgray, thick] (4,0) -- ++(180:0.8cm) arc (180:180-atan2(4,2):0.8cm) node at ($(167:0.6cm)+(4,0)$) {$\alpha$} -- cycle;
\draw[fill=lightgray, thick] (0,2) -- ++(-90:0.8cm) arc (-90:-90+atan2(2,4):0.8cm) node at ($(-60:0.5cm)+(0,2)$) {$\beta$} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that you need the `calc` library and you need to tweak the coordinates by hand if you change the size of the triangle. Of course you can parametrize to some extent by defining lengths (e.g. `\def\adjleg{4}` and `\def\oppleg{2}`) and use these in the figure. The angles are a bit more difficult, though.

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. I get [this image](http://i.imgur.com/VNWGoV4.png) instead using TeXLive2013.

Comment: There was a change in the `atan2` function from v2.x to v3 of `pgf`. The order of the arguments was swapped from `atan2(x,y)` to (the more common) `atan2(y,x)`. So the first should now be `atan2(2,4)`, and the second `atan2(4,2)`, not the other way around.