# Trouble marking angles with tkz-euclide

Tags: angle, tkz-euclide

After hearing of latex a few months ago and using the tex stackexchange numerous times to figure out problems I was having,  this is actually going to be my 1st question.

I was trying to find a way to easily draw markings of angles.
I came across a good answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96459/automatically-draw-and-labels-angles-of-a-triangle-in-tikz/96462#96462)

However when I use the `tkz-euclide` package with the `\tkzMarkAngle` command it creates an angle marking on the outside instead. (ie reflex angle)

Here's a simple example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,6); 
\coordinate (B) at (0,0); 
\coordinate (C) at (6,6);  
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\tkzMarkRightAngle[size=.4cm](B,A,C)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=.4cm](A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This gives me

[image]

`\tkzMarkRightAngle` works fine but I don't know why `\tkzMarkAngle` is doing what its doing.
All the other examples I've seen have the acute angle being marked except for mine.

Amy help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just invert the order of the points in this way:

```
\tkzMarkAngle[size=.4cm](C,B,A)
```

[image]