# Draw angle between two lines in a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, angle

I'm trying to draw an angle between two lines.

I have this code so far, but i cant draw a angle. How do I do it? I'm using PGF/TikZ.

```
\begin{figure}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
         ticks=none,
         axis lines = middle,
         axis line style={->},
         ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
         xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
         axis equal]
         \addplot[black, domain=0:0.7071] {x};
         \draw[black] (axis cs:0,0) circle [radius=1];
      \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!. Read [this](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize further with our format.

Comment: Similarly to [Automatically draw and labels angles of a triangle in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96459/13304), I think `\tkzMarkAngle` is very useful for this.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Don't forget TikZ 3.0.0: [Label angle with tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20826/label-angle-with-tikz/136971#136971)...

Comment: @PaulGaborit: absolutely right!! It's really time to switch to the new release ;)

Comment: Please do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than “user1234”.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `arc` operation can be used here. The general syntax as recommended by the TikZ/PGF manual (thanks to [@Tobi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4918/tobi) for the comment) is

```
\draw (<starting point>) arc [<options>];
```

with these options:

- `radius=<dim>`
- `x radius=<dim>`
- `y radius=<dim>`
- `start angle=<deg>`
- `end angle=<deg>`
- `delta angle=<deg>`

or a less readable version

```
\draw (<starting point>) arc (<start angle>:<end angle>:<radius>);
```

where `<radius>` can be a single length or `<dim> and <dim>` for different radii.

## Code

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      ticks=none,
      axis lines = middle,
      axis line style={->},
      ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
      xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
    axis equal]
    \addplot[black, domain=0:0.7071] {x};
    \draw[black] (axis cs:0,0) circle [radius=1];
    \draw (axis cs:.125,0)arc[radius=.25cm,start angle=0,end angle=45];
    % \draw (axis cs:.125,0)arc(0:45:.25cm); % same as above with different syntax
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Please note that the the official recommended syntax is `arc [options]`: “However, this syntax [using `(α:β:r)`] is harder to read, so the normal syntax [using options] should be preferred in general.” (`pgfmanual.pdf`, p. 144) So you may like to extend your answer ;-)

Comment: Thanks! This was the best answer so far to what I was looking for. But actually I didn't want to use any dimensions, I mean cm, mm whatever.  so I tried this:

\draw (axis cs:0.5,0) arc [radius=50,start angle=0,end angle=45]

which is exactly what I want!

Comment: @KevinC: I hope you don’t mind that I added some info :-) (btw. the @-notifications work only in comments, see [this](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and [that](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598) …)

Comment: @Tobi: No, not at all. Thank you very much for improving the answer `:)`

Answer (score 4):

With PSTricks. Like this?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(4,4)
    \pstGeonode
        (1,1){B}
        ([nodesep=2,angle=60]B){A}
        ([nodesep=2,angle=20]B){C}
    \pscircle(B){2}
    \psline(A)(B)(C)
    \psarc[origin={B}](B){1}{(C)}{(A)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Version 2

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \psline(-2,0)(2,0)
    \psline(0,-2)(0,2)
    \pnodes(0,0){B}(1;60){A}(1;20){C}
    \psline(A)(B)(C)
    \psarc[origin={B}](B){.2}{(C)}{(A)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]