# Marking right angles (structuralanalysis)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw this picture:

[image]

Until now, I have this, with the help of `structuralanalysis` package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{structuralanalysis}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45]
  \draw[thick, ->] (-{sqrt(8)},-{sqrt(8)}) arc (225:-45:4cm)node[below right] {$L$};
  \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (2.79,2.79);
   \draw[color=black] (1.75,1.2) node[left] {$R$};
   \draw[thick,->] (3,3) -- (4,4.5);
   \draw[color=black] (3.9,4.4) node[above] {$\varphi$};
   \draw[color=black] (4.7,2) node[above] {$w$};
   \draw[thick,->] (3,3) -- (4.5,2);
   \draw[thick, ->] (4,3.5) arc (-90:180:1cm)node[below] {$\psi$};
   \point{a}{-{sqrt(8)}}{-{sqrt(8)}};
   \support{3}{a}[45];
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

My question is how I can draw a right angle markings of the original drawing? I would draw each square using four points calculated manually (A, B, C, D, by example) and then

```
  \draw A--B--C--D--A;
```

but I think there must be a shorter way.

Comment: Related: [Insertion of perpendicular symbol at intersection of two perpendicular lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21752)

Comment: Here is a high voted question on marking angles answering your question [Automatically draw and labels angles of a triangle in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96459/automatically-draw-and-labels-angles-of-a-triangle-in-tikz)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to [Insertion of perpendicular symbol at intersection of two perpendicular lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21752) but with `pic`. The syntax is similar to the one of the `angle` library (which can be used to annotate angles of any degree with various styles.

I also adjusted your code and used

- polar coordinates `(<angle>:<radius>)`,
- named coordinates, and
- automatically placed nodes and coordinates along a path.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,angles,calc}
\usepackage{structuralanalysis}
\tikzset{
  angleR distance/.initial=.3cm,
  pics/angleR/.style args={#1--#2--#3}{% This asumes a right angle between #2, #1 and #3
    setup code={%
      % This is the same as
      % … let \p0=($(#2.center)-(#1.center)$),
      % \n0=(atan2(\y0,\x0) in …
      % and storing \n0 in \tikzAngleRotate (or using it directly)
      \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints
        {\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}%
      \let\tikzAngleRotate\pgfmathresult},
    foreground code={
      \path[pic actions, rotate=\tikzAngleRotate]
           ($(#2)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/angleR distance}!(#1)$)
        |- ($(#2)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/angleR distance}!(#3)$);}
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Triangle, auto=right, thick]
 \draw[->] (225:4) arc [start angle=225, end angle=-45, radius=4]
   coordinate[at start] (arc-start)
   node[at start, left] {$O$}
   node[below right] {$L$} coordinate[pos=2/3] (arc-tr);
 \draw[->, shorten >=\pgflinewidth] (0,0) -- node {$R$} (arc-tr);

 \coordinate (arc-tr') at ([shift=(45:.2cm)]arc-tr);
 \coordinate (O) at (0,0)
  coordinate (arc-start-e) at ([shift=(90+45:3)]arc-start);
 \draw[<->, shift=(arc-tr'), inner sep=.1667em] (45-90:1.5cm) coordinate (arc-tr'-A)
    -- node[at start] {$w$}       (0,0)                       coordinate (arc-tr'-B)
    -- node[at end]   {$\varphi$} (45:1.5cm)                  coordinate (arc-tr'-C);
 \draw[shift=(arc-tr'-C), ->] (-90:1cm)
   arc[start angle=-90, end angle=180, radius=1cm] node[left] {$\psi$};

 \support{3}{arc-start}[45];
 \pic[draw, thin] {angleR=arc-tr'-A--arc-tr'-B--arc-tr'-C};
 \pic[draw, thin, angleR distance=.15cm] {angleR=O--arc-start--arc-start-e};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I will explain for one of the right angle marks. First draw two coordinates

```
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (-{sqrt(8)},-{sqrt(8)});
```

Then draw a path with `5mm` length that is at right angle to the path `OA` like

```
\path (A) -- ($(A)!5mm!90:(O)$)coordinate (A1);
```

Let the end of this path be called `A1`. Now draw a path similarly but at an angle 45 to `OA` like

```
\path (A) -- ($(A)!2mm!45:(O)$)coordinate (A2);
```

and with angle `0` like

```
\path (A) -- ($(A)!5mm!(O)$)coordinate (A3);
```

Then draw the projection of `A2` on to path `AA1`

```
\draw (A2) -- ($(A)!(A2)!(A1)$);
```

and the projection of `A2` on path `AA3`

```
\draw (A2) -- ($(A)!(A2)!(O)$);
```

For the other one follow the same steps.

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{structuralanalysis}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45]
  \draw[thick, ->] (-{sqrt(8)},-{sqrt(8)}) arc (225:-45:4cm)node[below right] {$L$};
  \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (2.79,2.79);
   \draw[color=black] (1.75,1.2) node[left] {$R$};
   \draw[thick,->] (3,3) -- +(45:2cm) coordinate (AA);
   \draw[color=black] (3.9,4.4) node[above] {$\varphi$};
   \draw[color=black] (4.7,2) node[above] {$w$};
   \draw[thick,->] (3,3) -- +(-45:2cm) coordinate (BB);
   \draw[thick, ->] (3,3)+(1,0.1) arc (-90:180:1cm)node[below] {$\psi$};
   \point{a}{-{sqrt(8)}}{-{sqrt(8)}};
   \support{3}{a}[45];

   \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
   \coordinate (A) at (-{sqrt(8)},-{sqrt(8)});
   \path (A) -- ($(A)!5mm!90:(O)$)coordinate (A1);
   \path (A) -- ($(A)!2mm!45:(O)$)coordinate (A2);
   \path (A) -- ($(A)!5mm!(O)$)coordinate (A3);
   \draw (A2) -- ($(A)!(A2)!(A1)$);
   \draw (A2) -- ($(A)!(A2)!(O)$);

   \coordinate (OO) at (3,3);
   \path (3,3) -- +(0:4mm) coordinate (AB);   
   \draw (AB) -- ($(AA)!(AB)!(OO)$);
   \draw (AB) -- ($(BB)!(AB)!(OO)$);


 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

---

With `tkz-euclid`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}                 %% Add this
\usetkzobj{all}                          %% Add this
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{structuralanalysis}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45]
  \draw[thick, ->] (-{sqrt(8)},-{sqrt(8)}) arc (225:-45:4cm)node[below right] {$L$};
  \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (2.79,2.79);
   \draw[color=black] (1.75,1.2) node[left] {$R$};
   \draw[thick,->] (3,3) -- +(45:2cm) coordinate (AA);
   \draw[color=black] (3.9,4.4) node[above] {$\varphi$};
   \draw[color=black] (4.7,2) node[above] {$w$};
   \draw[thick,->] (3,3) -- +(-45:2cm) coordinate (BB);
   \draw[thick, ->] (3,3)+(1,0.1) arc (-90:180:1cm)node[below] {$\psi$};
   \point{a}{-{sqrt(8)}}{-{sqrt(8)}};
   \support{3}{a}[45];

   \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
   \coordinate (A) at (-{sqrt(8)},-{sqrt(8)});
   \path (A) -- ($(A)!5mm!90:(O)$)coordinate (A1);
   %\path (A) -- ($(A)!2mm!45:(O)$)coordinate (A2);
   \path (A) -- ($(A)!5mm!(O)$)coordinate (A3);
   \tkzMarkRightAngle(A1,A,A3)   %% Add this

   \coordinate (OO) at (3,3);
   \tkzMarkRightAngle(AA,OO,BB)     %% Add this


 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: If you want shorter way, use `tkz-euclide. It provides `\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,B,C)` where A, B, C are cordinates similar to A1, A, A3. That means, declare coordinates A1, A and A3 as in the answer and then  use `\tkzMarkRightAngle(A1,A,A3)`

Comment: Your answer works fine. But using `tkz-euclid`, I get an error, in my edited question I describe it.

Comment: @G.Aguilera I have added a `tkz-euclide` version.

Answer (score 3):

Harish showed the correct way, but you can also use some tricky ones.

These right angle marks can be drawn as little squares conveniently rotated and  shifted. You just need to know where is the angle origin and rotation.

Next code draws one mark with an squared empty node and the other one with a `rectangle`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{structuralanalysis}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45]
   \draw[thick, ->] (-{sqrt(8)},-{sqrt(8)}) arc (225:-45:4cm)node[below right] {$L$};
   \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (2.79,2.79);
   \draw[color=black] (1.75,1.2) node[left] {$R$};
   \draw[thick,->] (3,3) -- (4,4.5);
   \draw[color=black] (3.9,4.4) node[above] {$\varphi$};
   \draw[color=black] (4.7,2) node[above] {$w$};
   \draw[thick,->] (3,3) -- (4.5,2);
   \draw[thick, ->] (4,3.5) arc (-90:180:1cm)node[below] {$\psi$};
   \point{a}{-{sqrt(8)}}{-{sqrt(8)}};
   \support{3}{a}[45];

   \node[minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0pt, draw=green, 
     anchor=south west, rotate=-atan(1/1.5)] at (3,3) {};

   \begin{scope}[shift={(a)}, rotate=45]
      \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle ++(2mm,2mm);
   \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I ilke how you use `scope` to rotate the angle-mark. I ended up adapting this approach (I find it easy to remember and quite quick to fiddle with the angle of rotation), doing this minor change `\draw [red] (0,0) +(-2mm,0) |- +(0,2mm);` instead of the whole rectangle. (the whole rectangle is fine when everything is black, but if I color the angle-marker, I find it simpler to take a half-rectangle to begin with).