# How to draw this triangle

Tags: diagrams

How can I draw this diagram(labels included) ?
Is it also possible to label the right angle please.

[image: Result diagram]

Description of the image (please ignore if you can see the image):
a right angled triangle with a 60° angle and opposite to it a 30° angle.
It has labels for the degree and the length of its sides which are 1, 2 and sqrt(3).

Comment: Welcome, how far did you get with your efforts? Somebody will provide the code to finish.

Comment: See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96459/automatically-draw-and-labels-angles-of-a-triangle-in-tikz

Comment: http://texample.net/tikz/examples/tutorial/

Comment: See the pgfmanual. It contains this (or something very similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are also specialized packages like tkz-euclide but this is simple enough to be done without any additional package or library in Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[thick] (0,0) coordinate (A) -- ++ (0,-2) coordinate(B)
 node[midway,left]{$1$} -- ++({2*sqrt(3)},0) coordinate (C) 
 node[midway,below]{$\sqrt{3}$}--cycle node[midway,above]{$2$};
 \draw (A) -- ++(0,-0.4) arc(-90:-30:0.4) node[midway,below right] {$60^\circ$};
 \draw (B) -- ++(0.4,0) arc(00:90:0.4) node[midway,above right] {$90^\circ$};
 \draw (C) -- ++(-0.6,0) arc(180:150:0.6) node[pos=0.65,left] {$30^\circ$};
 \fill ([xshift=1.5mm,yshift=1.5mm]B) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]